# Woocommerce - Displaying variations inside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, loops, woocommerce

```
<?php

    switch ( $product->product_type ) {
        case "variable" :
            $link   = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $label  = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_text', __('Select options', 'woocommerce') );
        break;
        case "grouped" :
            $link   = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $label  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __('View options', 'woocommerce') );
        break;
        case "external" :
            $link   = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $label  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __('Read More', 'woocommerce') );
        break;
        default :
            $link   = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
            $label  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce') );
        break;
    }

    printf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_%s">%s</a>', $link, $product->id, $product->product_type, $label);

?>
```

I'm trying to get variations to display inside the loop so customers can add variable products to their cart from the shop page (please see screenshot below)...

http://cl.ly/image/42401k0X0X2I

I know I need to include the function-

```
get_available_variations();
```

And i'm pretty sure this already returns an array, it's just putting that array into a select dropdown + listing the variations (S,M,L,XL) and having a link to add that variation to the basket.

Cheers!

Comment: Where does the code at the top come from?

Comment: woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found your post while trying to solve the same problem. I finally found...

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    // Enqueue variation scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

    // Load the template
    woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
            'available_variations'  => $product->get_available_variations(),
            'attributes'            => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
            'selected_attributes'   => $product->get_variation_default_attributes()
        ) );
}
}
```

in

[woocommerce-template.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/woocommerce-template.php)

This works for me in loop/add-to-cart.php

```
switch ( $product->product_type ) {
        case "variable" :
            $link   = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $label  = woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
        break;
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The variations dropdown template file for single post pages is located here:
woocommerce\templates\single-product\add-to-cart\variable.php

Which requires the following script to pass the product variable information:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var product_variations_<?php echo $post->ID; ?> = <?php echo json_encode( $available_variations ) ?>;
</script>
```

as well as the following hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="" /> - where the value is the variation ID
```

I hope that is a start others can help build upon.

Comment: i placed the above snippet on my `loop/price.php` file. but the `$available_variations` outputs `null` on my side. is there anything else i forgot to include?

Answer (score 2):

I found on [Remi Corson's blog](http://www.remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-variable-product-with-variations-to-cart/) a simple way to do that.

Change the `href` value of the cart button with the following:

```
http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=[PRODUCT_ID]&variation_id=[VARIATION_ID]&attribute_pa_[ATTRIBUTE_SLUG]=[ATTRIBUTE_SLUG_VALUE]
```

Example:

```
http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&variation_id=456&attribute_pa_colour=black
```

With the `get_available_variations();` function is easy to get the variation values. For the product ID, you can use `get_the_ID();` function.

Comment: when am adding `$id = get_the_ID(); $variations = get_available_variations($id);` to my custom single page template(within theme folder i created woocommece/.....) am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_available_variations(). Any idea @Guilherme Marconi?